# How can I send an email to multiple recipients using the Mandrill API?

Tags: php, mandrill

I have found similar questions, but still not clear to me.
How can I send an email to multiple recipients using the Mandrill API?

The quantity of recipients may vary according to the information stored on the db:

```
$query = "SELECT emails FROM emails_table";
$data = mysql_query($query);
$n = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
$email[$n] = $row['emails'];
$n++;
}
```

So, emails will be stored in variables like this. E.g.

```
$email[0] = email_0@example.com;
$email[1] = email_1@example.com;
$email[2] = email_2@example.com;
```

And this is the Mandrill API:

```
require("/mandrill_mail/src/Mandrill.php");

try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('kWre_48F1lnJs3_39YM434z');//API KEY
    $message = array(
        'html' => 'message',
        'subject' => 'subject',
        'from_email' => 'my_mail@my_domain.com',
        'from_name' => 'My_Domain',
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => $email[0], //How can I add the other emails considering that the number of recipients will vary depending on the data in the db?
                'name' => 'Recipient Name',
                'type' => 'to'*/
            )
        ),
        'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'my_mail@my_domain.com'),
        'important' => false,
        'track_opens' => null,
        'track_clicks' => null,
        'auto_text' => null,
        'auto_html' => null,
        'inline_css' => null,
        'url_strip_qs' => null,
        'preserve_recipients' => false,
        'view_content_link' => null,
        'bcc_address' => $mail_bc,
        'tracking_domain' => null,
        'signing_domain' => null,
        'return_path_domain' => null,
        'merge' => true,
        'merge_language' => 'mailchimp',

    );
    $async = false;
    $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';

    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool);
}
```

Comment: how do you want to send the email? As *multiple separate emails* to those recipients? or as *one email* with many recipients?

Comment: The faster way. I think it is one email with many recipients.

Comment: @BenRowe What do we need to do if it is ` multiple separate emails to multiple recipients`?

Comment: you will need to iterate through each recipient individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// build the 'to' array
$query = "SELECT emails FROM emails_table";
$data = mysql_query($query);
$emails = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $emails[] = array(
        'email' => $row['emails'], 
        'type' => 'to'
    );
}
```

Then

```
require("/mandrill_mail/src/Mandrill.php");

try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('kWre_48F1lnJs3_39YM434z');//API KEY
    $message = array(
        'html' => 'message',
        'subject' => 'subject',
        'from_email' => 'my_mail@my_domain.com',
        'from_name' => 'My_Domain',
        'to' => $emails,
        'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'my_mail@my_domain.com'),
        'important' => false,
        'track_opens' => null,
        'track_clicks' => null,
        'auto_text' => null,
        'auto_html' => null,
        'inline_css' => null,
        'url_strip_qs' => null,
        'preserve_recipients' => false,
        'view_content_link' => null,
        'bcc_address' => $mail_bc,
        'tracking_domain' => null,
        'signing_domain' => null,
        'return_path_domain' => null,
        'merge' => true,
        'merge_language' => 'mailchimp',

    );
    $async = false;
    $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';

    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool);
}
```

Comment: are you sure about this method ? The api documentation says that it needs a single recipient's information in 'to' field

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The documentation is referring to having multiple email addresses within the `email` portion of the `to` field.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to loop through $emails array and dynamically send the email to each email address.

```
foreach($emails as $email){

try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('kWre_48F1lnJs3_39YM434z');//API KEY
    $message = array(
        'html' => 'message',
        'subject' => 'subject',
        'from_email' => 'my_mail@my_domain.com',
        'from_name' => 'My_Domain',
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => $email, 
                'name' => 'Recipient Name',
                'type' => 'to'*/
            )
        ),
        'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'my_mail@my_domain.com'),
        'important' => false,
        'track_opens' => null,
        'track_clicks' => null,
        'auto_text' => null,
        'auto_html' => null,
        'inline_css' => null,
        'url_strip_qs' => null,
        'preserve_recipients' => false,
        'view_content_link' => null,
        'bcc_address' => $mail_bc,
        'tracking_domain' => null,
        'signing_domain' => null,
        'return_path_domain' => null,
        'merge' => true,
        'merge_language' => 'mailchimp',

    );
    $async = false;
    $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';

    $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool);
} 

}
```

You can also send a new message through Mandrill using a template.However make sure you know about it`s limits

For SMTP messages, you may send to up to 1,000 recipients at a time. If you’re sending to more recipients, simultaneous and subsequent connections are permitted.

For the API, there’s no recipient limitation, but the JSON provided per API call must be less than 10MB. We strongly recommend smaller recipient batches for easier troubleshooting.

> For SMTP messages, you may send to up to 1,000 recipients at a time.
>   If you’re sending to more recipients, simultaneous and subsequent
>   connections are permitted.
>
> For the API, there’s no recipient limitation, but the JSON provided
>   per API call must be less than 10MB. We strongly recommend smaller
>   recipient batches for easier troubleshooting.